# sql group by with count and add totals row

Tags: count, group-by

So my situation. Got a table with few thousand entries, I took one column and counted the number of the same entries.

```
  SELECT mycolumn, COUNT(*)
  FROM mytable
  WHERE myid = 6867
  GROUP BY mycolumn
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Outputs:

```
6 885
1 715
4 562
5 557
2 232
3 181
```

I get the desired results. Now all I need is to add a bottom row with a sum of all counted entries.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would do this in some reporting tool, like SSRS, not SQL.

To do it in SQL, add a UNION statement:

```
UNION ALL

SELECT 0, COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
WHERE myid = 6867;
```